# How to collapse/aggregate values into several columns of dicts

Tags: python, pandas

I want to collapse the rows of a dataframe such that each row represents an hour (the source data goes down to minute granularity).  I don't want to lose the data, instead I want to create a dict so that the key of the dict is the minute (the source data doesn't go down to seconds) and then have the value be the value for that minute.  See my brute force example at the bottom for what I'm really getting at.

I have data that looks something like this

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import itertools
import random
from copy import deepcopy
fruits=['apple','banana','pear']
dts=[datetime(2022,1,1)+timedelta(minutes=x*random.randint(1,9)) for x in range(48)]
df=pd.DataFrame([x for x in itertools.product(fruits, dts)], columns=['fruit','dt'])
df['value1']=[random.randrange(0,100) for i in range(df.shape[0])]
df['value2']=[random.randrange(0,100) for i in range(df.shape[0])]
df['value3']=[random.randrange(0,100) for i in range(df.shape[0])]
#   fruit           dt       value1 value2 value3
# 0 apple   2022-01-01 00:00:00 56  55  65
# 1 apple   2022-01-01 00:02:00 98  67  16
# 2 apple   2022-01-01 00:12:00 52  19  23
# 3 apple   2022-01-01 00:09:00 0   60  82
# 4 apple   2022-01-01 00:08:00 94  51  22
# ...   ... ... ... ... ...
# 139   pear    2022-01-01 00:43:00 14  49  37
# 140   pear    2022-01-01 02:56:00 92  98  73
# 141   pear    2022-01-01 02:15:00 9   5   99
# 142   pear    2022-01-01 03:04:00 92  39  10
# 143   pear    2022-01-01 05:29:00 52  61  65
```

The best I can do using reasonable syntax is:

```
df['minute']=[x.minute for x in df.dt]
df['hour']=[x.hour+1 for x in df.dt]
df['date']=[x.replace(hour=0, minute=0) for x in df.dt]

def splitdict(x):
    mydict={}
    x=list(x)
    for elem in x:
        mydict[elem[0]]=elem[1]
    return(mydict)

df.groupby(['fruit','date','hour']).apply(lambda x: splitdict(zip(df.minute,df.value1)))
```

Of course, this doesn't actually work (so I'll spare you the output).  It returns the same dict for every row and it would only work for `value1` (ie. I don't know how to get the results for `value1, value2, value3` at once)  I thought if I did a `deepcopy` that would resolve the repeating dict but it didn't so I took that out.

I did a horrendous for loop to brute force what I want.  That looks like this:

```
#brute force
uniq=df.drop_duplicates(['fruit','date','hour'])
uniq=uniq[['fruit','date','hour']]
results=[]
for index, row in uniq.iterrows():
    mydict=(df[(df['date']==row['date']) & (df['hour']==row['hour']) & (df['fruit']==row['fruit'])].loc[:,['minute','value1','value2','value3']]).to_dict('records')
    value1dict={mydict[i]['minute']:mydict[i]['value1'] for i in range(len(mydict))}
    value2dict={mydict[i]['minute']:mydict[i]['value2'] for i in range(len(mydict))}
    value3dict={mydict[i]['minute']:mydict[i]['value3'] for i in range(len(mydict))}
    results.append(pd.DataFrame({'date':row['date'], 'hour':row['hour'], 'fruit':row['fruit'] , 'value1':[value1dict], 'value2':[value2dict], 'value3':[value3dict]}))
    
results=pd.concat(results)


#   date    hour    fruit   value1  value2  value3
# 0 2022-01-01  1   apple   {0: 56, 2: 98, 12: 52, 9: 0, 8: 94, 30: 90, 48: 92, 21: 16, 45: 9, 40: 58, 24: 31, 13: 45, 28: 86, 57: 47, 56: 66, 34: 69, 39: 12, 41: 92, 43: 12}  {0: 55, 2: 67, 12: 19, 9: 60, 8: 51, 30: 95, 48: 62, 21: 97, 45: 1, 40: 89, 24: 52, 13: 5, 28: 67, 57: 16, 56: 13, 34: 54, 39: 86, 41: 45, 43: 50}  {0: 65, 2: 16, 12: 23, 9: 82, 8: 22, 30: 76, 48: 98, 21: 23, 45: 14, 40: 87, 24: 45, 13: 87, 28: 29, 57: 75, 56: 26, 34: 25, 39: 70, 41: 97, 43: 89}
# 0 2022-01-01  2   apple   {12: 31, 39: 42, 42: 87, 20: 86, 45: 62, 28: 86, 55: 59, 44: 83, 0: 26, 2: 97, 36: 55, 24: 44}  {12: 74, 39: 55, 42: 16, 20: 12, 45: 92, 28: 2, 55: 98, 44: 44, 0: 63, 2: 54, 36: 76, 24: 55}   {12: 97, 39: 81, 42: 76, 20: 71, 45: 26, 28: 56, 55: 61, 44: 93, 0: 90, 2: 87, 36: 28, 24: 52}
# 0 2022-01-01  3   apple   {15: 72, 8: 84, 24: 97, 0: 54, 30: 10, 12: 50, 55: 51, 56: 31}  {15: 30, 8: 42, 24: 96, 0: 76, 30: 58, 12: 44, 55: 82, 56: 57}  {15: 41, 8: 11, 24: 40, 0: 89, 30: 22, 12: 51, 55: 57, 56: 60}
# 0 2022-01-01  5   apple   {3: 14, 56: 79, 0: 25}  {3: 3, 56: 61, 0: 49}   {3: 2, 56: 29, 0: 32}
# 0 2022-01-01  4   apple   {52: 53, 0: 50, 4: 53}  {52: 32, 0: 64, 4: 26}  {52: 88, 0: 28, 4: 59}
# 0 2022-01-01  6   apple   {42: 40, 29: 52}    {42: 30, 29: 82}    {42: 50, 29: 33}
# 0 2022-01-01  1   banana  {0: 6, 2: 10, 12: 43, 9: 77, 8: 19, 30: 59, 48: 67, 21: 17, 45: 92, 40: 69, 24: 25, 13: 86, 28: 81, 57: 72, 56: 35, 34: 22, 39: 61, 41: 8, 43: 56}  {0: 63, 2: 92, 12: 49, 9: 22, 8: 2, 30: 92, 48: 96, 21: 21, 45: 62, 40: 23, 24: 77, 13: 41, 28: 64, 57: 49, 56: 30, 34: 59, 39: 63, 41: 54, 43: 85} {0: 27, 2: 83, 12: 35, 9: 37, 8: 70, 30: 94, 48: 16, 21: 19, 45: 71, 40: 5, 24: 26, 13: 91, 28: 16, 57: 42, 56: 8, 34: 31, 39: 93, 41: 57, 43: 65}
# 0 2022-01-01  2   banana  {12: 0, 39: 53, 42: 13, 20: 91, 45: 88, 28: 66, 55: 46, 44: 24, 0: 41, 2: 32, 36: 69, 24: 11}   {12: 83, 39: 21, 42: 41, 20: 81, 45: 79, 28: 37, 55: 28, 44: 2, 0: 51, 2: 87, 36: 63, 24: 82}   {12: 6, 39: 57, 42: 18, 20: 3, 45: 74, 28: 58, 55: 46, 44: 25, 0: 45, 2: 96, 36: 37, 24: 14}
# 0 2022-01-01  3   banana  {15: 10, 8: 14, 24: 60, 0: 48, 30: 82, 12: 70, 55: 39, 56: 4}   {15: 81, 8: 55, 24: 8, 0: 64, 30: 72, 12: 45, 55: 79, 56: 45}   {15: 95, 8: 90, 24: 36, 0: 47, 30: 88, 12: 12, 55: 86, 56: 75}
# 0 2022-01-01  5   banana  {3: 47, 56: 39, 0: 60}  {3: 60, 56: 15, 0: 72}  {3: 48, 56: 86, 0: 16}
# 0 2022-01-01  4   banana  {52: 49, 0: 30, 4: 86}  {52: 39, 0: 85, 4: 5}   {52: 64, 0: 22, 4: 96}
# 0 2022-01-01  6   banana  {42: 2, 29: 26} {42: 15, 29: 54}    {42: 61, 29: 58}
# 0 2022-01-01  1   pear    {0: 39, 2: 55, 12: 25, 9: 98, 8: 14, 30: 82, 48: 59, 21: 77, 45: 8, 40: 75, 24: 19, 13: 92, 28: 39, 57: 63, 56: 95, 34: 77, 39: 77, 41: 41, 43: 14} {0: 54, 2: 11, 12: 63, 9: 12, 8: 38, 30: 34, 48: 96, 21: 27, 45: 19, 40: 87, 24: 83, 13: 28, 28: 22, 57: 25, 56: 38, 34: 66, 39: 80, 41: 80, 43: 49}    {0: 98, 2: 71, 12: 97, 9: 54, 8: 70, 30: 22, 48: 31, 21: 4, 45: 47, 40: 42, 24: 28, 13: 68, 28: 65, 57: 73, 56: 32, 34: 1, 39: 73, 41: 39, 43: 37}
# 0 2022-01-01  2   pear    {12: 93, 39: 57, 42: 12, 20: 98, 45: 69, 28: 60, 55: 77, 44: 16, 0: 96, 2: 16, 36: 76, 24: 15}  {12: 23, 39: 63, 42: 59, 20: 15, 45: 66, 28: 50, 55: 18, 44: 87, 0: 33, 2: 15, 36: 9, 24: 90}   {12: 80, 39: 50, 42: 98, 20: 12, 45: 54, 28: 90, 55: 67, 44: 37, 0: 86, 2: 2, 36: 51, 24: 64}
# 0 2022-01-01  3   pear    {15: 9, 8: 71, 24: 3, 0: 94, 30: 53, 12: 90, 55: 28, 56: 92}    {15: 5, 8: 85, 24: 77, 0: 53, 30: 26, 12: 62, 55: 2, 56: 98}    {15: 99, 8: 4, 24: 14, 0: 86, 30: 50, 12: 17, 55: 70, 56: 73}
# 0 2022-01-01  5   pear    {3: 57, 56: 2, 0: 65}   {3: 32, 56: 16, 0: 90}  {3: 88, 56: 74, 0: 80}
# 0 2022-01-01  4   pear    {52: 23, 0: 32, 4: 92}  {52: 4, 0: 93, 4: 39}   {52: 30, 0: 97, 4: 10}
# 0 2022-01-01  6   pear    {42: 43, 29: 52}    {42: 63, 29: 61}    {42: 80, 29: 65}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC

```
cols_to_dict = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']

out = df.assign(date=df['dt'].dt.date, hour=df['dt'].dt.hour, minute=df['dt'].dt.minute) \
        .set_index('minute').groupby(['date', 'hour', 'fruit'])[cols_to_dict] \
        .agg(dict).sort_index(level=['date', 'fruit', 'hour']).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
>>> out
          date  hour   fruit                                             value1                                             value2                                             value3
0   2022-01-01     0   apple  {0: 67, 9: 82, 6: 33, 21: 74, 16: 99, 20: 82, ...  {0: 46, 9: 47, 6: 57, 21: 21, 16: 8, 20: 96, 1...  {0: 25, 9: 42, 6: 1, 21: 99, 16: 63, 20: 47, 1...
1   2022-01-01     1   apple  {3: 30, 0: 36, 5: 81, 24: [51, 57, 59], 25: 77...  {3: 40, 0: 32, 5: 14, 24: [18, 49, 58], 25: 60...  {3: 83, 0: 80, 5: 17, 24: [37, 24, 34], 25: 16...
2   2022-01-01     2   apple  {0: 49, 24: [64, 26], 40: 6, 18: 48, 4: 11, 16...  {0: 77, 24: [53, 77], 40: 80, 18: 11, 4: 76, 1...  {0: 0, 24: [62, 75], 40: 44, 18: 13, 4: 56, 16...
3   2022-01-01     3   apple             {20: [88, 88], 28: 94, 54: 48, 25: 34}             {20: [68, 34], 28: 55, 54: 15, 25: 46}             {20: [16, 49], 28: 50, 54: 11, 25: 26}
4   2022-01-01     4   apple                                           {36: 91}                                           {36: 86}                                           {36: 95}
5   2022-01-01     5   apple                            {33: 21, 36: 70, 8: 89}                            {33: 34, 36: 66, 8: 69}                            {33: 39, 36: 38, 8: 92}
6   2022-01-01     6   apple                                           {45: 87}                                           {45: 80}                                           {45: 24}
7   2022-01-01     0  banana  {0: 67, 9: 67, 6: 64, 21: 80, 16: 29, 20: 85, ...  {0: 30, 9: 33, 6: 4, 21: 64, 16: 29, 20: 59, 1...  {0: 92, 9: 37, 6: 93, 21: 40, 16: 49, 20: 97, ...
8   2022-01-01     1  banana  {3: 12, 0: 73, 5: 6, 24: [19, 81, 44], 25: 11,...  {3: 41, 0: 22, 5: 86, 24: [68, 41, 7], 25: 25,...  {3: 94, 0: 52, 5: 15, 24: [19, 59, 12], 25: 2,...
9   2022-01-01     2  banana  {0: 49, 24: [36, 87], 40: 35, 18: 26, 4: 21, 1...  {0: 96, 24: [30, 45], 40: 86, 18: 33, 4: 2, 16...  {0: 53, 24: [39, 22], 40: 84, 18: 7, 4: 47, 16...
10  2022-01-01     3  banana             {20: [45, 27], 28: 58, 54: 96, 25: 90}             {20: [14, 22], 28: 49, 54: 14, 25: 90}             {20: [94, 50], 28: 19, 54: 26, 25: 65}
11  2022-01-01     4  banana                                           {36: 64}                                           {36: 62}                                           {36: 43}
12  2022-01-01     5  banana                             {33: 83, 36: 4, 8: 34}                            {33: 13, 36: 36, 8: 37}                             {33: 2, 36: 63, 8: 94}
13  2022-01-01     6  banana                                           {45: 22}                                            {45: 2}                                            {45: 0}
14  2022-01-01     0    pear  {0: 55, 9: 29, 6: 30, 21: 57, 16: 37, 20: 63, ...  {0: 74, 9: 38, 6: 18, 21: 47, 16: 47, 20: 34, ...  {0: 25, 9: 75, 6: 36, 21: 60, 16: 94, 20: 68, ...
15  2022-01-01     1    pear  {3: 20, 0: 22, 5: 1, 24: [94, 27, 44], 25: 73,...  {3: 59, 0: 50, 5: 7, 24: [34, 15, 28], 25: 24,...  {3: 90, 0: 71, 5: 75, 24: [4, 4, 63], 25: 73, ...
16  2022-01-01     2    pear  {0: 42, 24: [83, 98], 40: 83, 18: 34, 4: 58, 1...  {0: 55, 24: [13, 50], 40: 39, 18: 37, 4: 68, 1...  {0: 69, 24: [80, 49], 40: 80, 18: 82, 4: 13, 1...
17  2022-01-01     3    pear              {20: [33, 50], 28: 47, 54: 16, 25: 0}             {20: [28, 26], 28: 74, 54: 66, 25: 13}              {20: [40, 67], 28: 88, 54: 96, 25: 4}
18  2022-01-01     4    pear                                           {36: 46}                                           {36: 28}                                           {36: 97}
19  2022-01-01     5    pear                            {33: 27, 36: 23, 8: 57}                            {33: 71, 36: 82, 8: 57}                            {33: 23, 36: 88, 8: 91}
20  2022-01-01     6    pear                                           {45: 83}                                           {45: 45}                                            {45: 3}
```

Comment: Great :) Do you need some explanation about the code?

Comment: Now that I see it, I get it.  Correct me if I'm wrong, the trick is in the initial `set_index` followed up by being able to just pass `dict` to `agg` directly.  From what I had read, the function that you feed to agg can only see each column at a time but I guess by setting the index to minute, it "cheats" that paradigm such that `dict` is acting on the combination of the minute index and the data in the `cols_to_dict`

Comment: If only I could come up with the solution instead of just being able to explain it after the fact.

Comment: I'm sure that for a similar problem you will find the solution yourself next time!